# Reposition colorbar in plotly and change color scale (R)

Tags: r, plotly, colorbar

I'm creating a `scattermapbox` plot using `plotly` and would like to:

1. Make the colorbar horizontal and position it on top my plot
2. Change the colorscale to shades of red and rename it to 'Elevation'

I've tried to follow the examples online but it doesn't work:

1. I added `legend = list(orientation = 'h')` to the `layout` but it made no difference. (2nd example here: https://plotly.com/r/scattermapbox/)
2. Added `coloraxis = list(colorscale = "Reds")` to the `layout` following the (first) example on https://plotly.com/r/scattermapbox/ without success
3. Other examples show it is possible to rename the `colorbar` by adding a named list to `marker` by `marker = list(..., colorbar = list(title = 'My title'))`. There's no parameter named `colorbar` in the reference documentation. (example here: https://plotly.com/r/colorscales/)

On a side note, I have a mapbox token, yet, the plot appears to work with a few styles only.

**Data**

Sharing 50 uniformly spaced points from the entire dataset (6000 points):

```
structure(list(lat = c(45.547955, 45.549801, 45.551437, 45.554653, 
45.559059, 45.560158, 45.563854, 45.567379, 45.5715069, 45.575817, 
45.579056, 45.582672, 45.586857, 45.591194, 45.59362, 45.597103, 
45.601231, 45.605034, 45.608997, 45.611233, 45.615376, 45.61932, 
45.622749, 45.625629, 45.628456, 45.631489, 45.631611, 45.632305, 
45.630135, 45.626793, 45.623497, 45.620045, 45.615589, 45.610992, 
45.606541, 45.602821, 45.599106, 45.595169, 45.591198, 45.5872079, 
45.582672, 45.578587, 45.57476, 45.570515, 45.565872, 45.56226, 
45.55862, 45.555603, 45.552097, 45.548283), lon = c(-73.666939, 
-73.668861, -73.674332, -73.673698, -73.672272, -73.66761, -73.664688, 
-73.661179, -73.660103, -73.658028, -73.657333, -73.654381, -73.652786, 
-73.651154, -73.648354, -73.644836, -73.64328, -73.641556, -73.63961, 
-73.637321, -73.635498, -73.632965, -73.629128, -73.624321, -73.620491, 
-73.615967, -73.613396, -73.61422, -73.618103, -73.622635, -73.627571, 
-73.632332, -73.635414, -73.637466, -73.638702, -73.640244, -73.643547, 
-73.646996, -73.649826, -73.651886, -73.652626, -73.6558, -73.6588359, 
-73.660416, -73.662086, -73.665947, -73.668335, -73.671501, -73.666359, 
-73.667671), ele = c(30.2, 27, 26.6, 25.7999999, 23.2, 26.7999999, 
20, 24, 22.7999999, 20.6, 19, 22.2, 19.2, 17.3999999, 25.2, 25.2, 
17, 16.6, 15.3999999, 17, 15.2, 15.6, 16.3999999, 16.7999999, 
17.7999999, 17.6, 24.3999999, 18.2, 18.6, 18.6, 19.2, 17, 17.2, 
18.7999999, 23.7999999, 27.7999999, 27.7999999, 26, 30.7999999, 
27.2, 29.2, 24, 23.7999999, 26.6, 24.7999999, 26.2, 31, 31, 31.2, 
32.6)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fb33c8118e0>)
```

**Code**

```
plt <- plot_mapbox(data = track, mode = 'scattermapbox',
                   lat = ~lat, lon = ~lon, color = ~ele) %>% 
  layout(mapbox = list(style = 'carto-positron', zoom = 10, # open-street-map works, but light, dark, basic don't work 
                  center = list(lon = track[, mean(lon)], lat = track[, mean(lat)])), 
    margin = list(l = 0, r = 0, t = 0, b = 0), 
    legend = list(orientation = 'h'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `%>% colorbar()` with parameters at https://plotly.com/r/reference/#scatter-marker-colorbar

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow and many  thanks for your answer. Could you please provide more details?